# Symfony login form redirect to hash

Tags: symfony, redirect, fragment

Anyone knows a way for standard Symfony login form to redirect to url with hash part like this: `http://sample.com/dashoard#something_here` The redirect works as should but hash part is gone after login redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Set `default_target_path` option

```
security:
    firewalls:
        xxx:
            ...
            form_login:
                ...
                default_target_path: /#qwerty
                ...
```

Comment: But I do not want to have the default path. We have a AJAX website that uses content past # as the path for AJAX call, so there might be: ```

Comment: ``` http:\\sample.com\container_1\view_2#get_column_content``` and so forth, I would like to make those link usable with login page.